# How to correctly use toFixed in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a line of code in my chart configuration that looks like this:

```
titleAccessor: d => (d.key === 'Random') ? `£${+((d.value).toFixed(2))}` : `£${+((d.value.quantity).toFixed(2))}`,
```

The above is used in a pie chart. When I have the `toFixed` set to 2, one of the segments of the pie chart is displaying £747.6 with no second decimal place. When I set `tofixed` to 3, it displays as £747.596.

Am I wrong to thing when it is set to 2 it should display £747.60? The other segments all have two decimal places but don't end in a zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are first converting your value to a string with fixed decimals via [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) - but then you convert this fixed string back to a number.

Details:

```js
const value = 747.6;
const valFixed = value.toFixed(2);
// toFixed works correctly an converts your number to this string: "747.60"
console.log(valFixed); 

const fixedToNum = +valFixed;
// the "+" operator converts the string "747.60" back to a number: 747.6
console.log(fixedToNum); // number 747.6
```

see this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/9d3jyr1g/5/)

in your case: `£${+((d.value).toFixed(2))}`

- `(d.value).toFixed(2)`: converts d.value to a string with 2 decimals
- `+((d.value).toFixed(2))`: the + operator converts this string back to a number